# Signal: Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: c, mpi

When I did the mpi prgramming and excute it on a single process,the system show me   "Signal: Segmentation fault (11)" and "Signal code: Invalid permissions (2)" ,but this programm could works find when execute without the MPI wrap, I mean if just execute without the MPI_Init() staffs, it works fine

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int numprocs,myid,read,i,allocatedjobs,j,current_worker_uc,uc_master_total=0;//i is definded by teacher
    int array[0];
    char * buf;
    char * worker_buf;
    int worker_result;
    int number_amount;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);

         if (numprocs==1){
            // /* trivial single cpu case */
                     read=buf_read(buf,buf+BUF_SIZE);   

             while(read)
             {
                 //printf("Actual number read is:%d\n",read);               
                         if(read==0){break;}
                         int current_buf_uc=count_uc(buf,read);
                         uc_all=(uc_all+current_buf_uc)%10+(uc_all+current_buf_uc)/10;
                         if(read<BUF_SIZE){break;}
                         read=buf_read(buf,buf+BUF_SIZE);

             }
             fclose(stdin);
             printf("%d\n",uc_all);     

        }
 MPI_Finalize();
          return 0;

}

int buf_read(char * buf, const char * end) {
    int count;
    count = fread(buf, 1, end - buf, stdin);
    if (count > 0 && buf[count - 1] == '\n') {
        --count;
    }
    return count;
}

int count_uc(char buf[],int size)
{

    int a = buf[0] - '0';
    int uc = -1;
    int j = 0;
    while (j<(size - 1))
    {
        int b = buf[j + 1] - '0';
        uc = (a + b) % 10 + (a + b) / 10;
        a = uc;
        ++j;
    }
    return uc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`buf` is used uninitialized in

```
read=buf_read(buf,buf+BUF_SIZE);
```

You need an array

```
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
```

or a pointer to an allocated space

```
char *buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
```

in order to store the block readed by `fread`